# How to add a blur boost to blurring?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, blur

When blurring any image I want to increase the effect of the blur. Is this possible by adding some kind of blur boost?

This is the code I use to blur:

```
- (void)Blur:(UIView *)view {
    UIView *blurView = nil;

    if([UIBlurEffect class]) {
        UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]; //Can do dark, light or extra light here
        blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
        blurView.frame = view.frame;

    } else {
        blurView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
    }

    [blurView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [view addSubview:blurView];
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[blurView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(blurView)]];
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[blurView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(blurView)]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the behavior of a UIVisualEffectView. If you want your own blur, you'll need to use a blur CIFilter or a third-party library that can do the same kind thing (e.g. GPUImage).